# C# Fastest way to increment a byte array used as an integer counter?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am using a segmented integer counter (byte array) in a parallel CTR implementation (encryption). The counter needs to be incremented in sizes corresponding to the blocks of data being processed by each processor. So, the number needs to be incremented by more than a single bit value. In other words.. the byte array is acting as a Big Integer, and I need to increase the sum value of the byte array by an integer factor. 
I am currently using the methods shown below using a while loop, but I am wondering if there is a bit wise method (& | ^ etc), as using a loop seems very wasteful.. any ideas?

```
private void Increment(byte[] Counter)
{
    int j = Counter.Length;
    while (--j >= 0 && ++Counter[j] == 0) { }
}

/// <summary>
/// Increase a byte array by a numerical value
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Counter">Original byte array</param>
/// <param name="Count">Number to increase by</param>
/// <returns>Array with increased value [byte[]]</returns>
private byte[] Increase(byte[] Counter, Int32 Count)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[Counter.Length];

    Buffer.BlockCopy(Counter, 0, buffer, 0, Counter.Length);

    for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        Increment(buffer);

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: "using a loop seems very wasteful" premature optimization is the root of all evil, if there is no performance botleneck there is no problem in your code, and if there is no problem there is no solution either. What i wan't to say, do you really want this?

Comment: althought you can get rid off you double boxed loop very easy just increase every byte value by the Count and not Count times by one. Still my first comment applies.

Comment: If there is a bitwise way of doing this, and it is faster, then yes, it is a valid optimization..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard O(n) multi-precision add goes like this (assuming [0] is LSB):

```
static void Add(byte[] dst, byte[] src)
{
    int carry = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < dst.Length; ++i)
    {
        byte odst = dst[i];
        byte osrc = i < src.Length ? src[i] : (byte)0;

        byte ndst = (byte)(odst + osrc + carry);

        dst[i] = ndst;
        carry = ndst < odst ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

It can help to think of this is terms of grade-school arithmetic, which is really all it is:

```
  129
+ 123
-----
```

Remember, where you'd perform an add and carry for each digit, starting from the left (the least-significant digit)? In this case, each digit is a byte in your array.

Rather than roll your own, have you considered using the arbitrary-precision [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx)? It was actually created specifically for .NET's own crypto stuff.

Comment: That would (likely) be very slow in comparison, and would require the library reference.

Comment: Actually, I migrated from a similar carry function, the current one is faster. Each counter has to be a unique array (because it runs inside the parallel loop, and each thread will increment that counter with every block processed).

Comment: This loops the array once, yours loops it `count` times... I don't see how yours could possibly be faster.

Comment: But where is the count? I need to increment it by a specific amount, say.. 256 or 1024..

Comment: @John: I wouldn't be so quick to dismiss `BigInteger`. It has the benefit of proven correctness, and a lot of really smart people worked to make it as fast as possible. I'd certainly give it a shot before trying to roll my own.

Comment: Under the hood, BigInteger is implemented as a uint[], so it works in the same fashion as Cory Nelson's Add(), but in blocks of 32 bits.  I think you're re-inventing the wheel here, John.

Comment: People.. look at the context please.. this is a CTR implementation, as in AES CTR.. every CTR implementation uses bytes.. Conversion to and from BigInteger to bytes would be expensive and impractical.

Comment: @John, `count` would be translated into a multiprecision-format byte array and passed as `src` here.

Comment: Actually I am re-working the method, only problem is endian order is reversed with your method..

Comment: Ok, I got this method working faster than my original implementation.. but the array still comes out in reverse order, so I have to run an array.reverse at the bottom of your method to get the correct counter value.. any ideas on how to eliminate that?

Comment: Actually scratch my last.. it only works if the counter is initialized at 0.

Answer (score 1):

I used a variation of Cory Nelsons answer that creates the array with the correct endian order and returns a new array. This is quite a bit faster then the method first posted.. thanks for the help.

```
private byte[] Increase(byte[] Counter, int Count)
{
    int carry = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[Counter.Length];
    int offset = buffer.Length - 1;
    byte[] cnt = BitConverter.GetBytes(Count);
    byte osrc, odst, ndst;

    Buffer.BlockCopy(Counter, 0, buffer, 0, Counter.Length);

    for (int i = offset; i > 0; i--)
    {
        odst = buffer[i];
        osrc = offset - i < cnt.Length ? cnt[offset - i] : (byte)0;
        ndst = (byte)(odst + osrc + carry);
        carry = ndst < odst ? 1 : 0;
        buffer[i] = ndst;
    }

    return buffer;
}
```